# How to add pulse animation in asymmetric on marker

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, openstreetmap, ngx-leaflet

I`ve problem with adding animation on marker in leaflet lib

I use

```
new L.Icon({ iconUrl: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png',
     shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
     iconSize: [25, 41],
     iconAnchor: [12, 41],
     popupAnchor: [1, -34],
     shadowSize: [41, 41]
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id='map' style="height:600px;"></div>`
```

I tried to use https://github.com/mapshakers/leaflet-icon-pulse

But it does not work.

so have You any idea how can i make this?

One more, `className` in Icon or `divIcon` is ignored, when i put this in .css file

Comment: Hi @Arek Szumacher Did you check my answer? Did it solve your issue?

Comment: I found the way. In Angular project , in the structure, should add class not in .css , but in global style .scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961549/pulsating-leaflet-marker-using-css3-animations) and adjust it in angular

```
// define the marker path icon for web-pack not to be confused 
const markerIcon = {
      icon: L.icon({
       iconSize: [25, 41],
       iconAnchor: [10, 41],
       popupAnchor: [2, -40],
       // specify the path here
       iconUrl:
          "https://cdn.rawgit.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png",
       shadowUrl:
          "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png"
   })
};

// Define an icon called animatedCircleIcon and set the css
const animatedCircleIcon = {
      icon: L.divIcon({
       className: "css-icon",
       html: '<div class="gps_ring"></div>',
       iconSize: [18, 22]
    })
 };

 // add the marker icon
 L.marker([50.5, 30.5], markerIcon).addTo(map);
 // add the animatedCircleIcon
 L.marker([50.5, 30.5], animatedCircleIcon).addTo(map);
```

and then in styles:

```
.gps_ring {
  border: 3px solid red;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /*opacity: 0.0*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/893xj6qq2)

**Edit**

I saw later that you have already written asymmetric so if you want an example using ngx-leaflet you should use this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/1yz2y1kw37)